# Persistent connection to SQL from a .NET client (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

The client (C#) connects to SQL Server (2017 - 2022) using connection pooling. The records, he is working with, needs to be locked. This is solved by writing a record to a user locking table on SQL (standard table).
In order to check that the lock is "live", a global temporary table (##table_GUID) is also created and its name is stored in the record on that table.
Here, a feature of SQL Server is used, which deletes the temporary table after detecting that the connection that created the temporary table is closed for any reason.

The scheduled process checks the user locking table and if it finds an active lock for which there is no temporary table, it releases the lock.
Until then, everything works without the slightest problem and to my complete satisfaction.

The problem arises in the case of long-lasting locks. The client is unable to create SQL Management Studio-style connections where the connection is dedicated to a specific client process. It even happens, that the global temporary table is deleted, although the given client is constantly connected.

Question: how to create a persisted connection from C# .NET to SQL Server, whose session_id (or @@spid) would not change and is closed (or return to the pool) when instructed by the client?

Comment: If you don't close or dispose the persistent connection, it will remain open while it's in scope unless it is terminated due to a network reset or the session killed on the server. You say the client is constantly connected but that must not be the case.

Comment: @DanGuzman: What you mean: "persistent connection"? I tried different settings in the connection string, do not use Dispose, do not use Using, etc., and I did not achieve the desired result - after some time of inactivity, the connection closes, and vice versa, when I find out its session_id and do Dispose, the given session_id does not disappear from the list of user connections on SQL

Comment: The connection will be returned to the pool when it goes out of scope. Add the code where you are declaring and using the connection.

Comment: The normal usage of `SqlConnection`s is to keep them within the scope of a single method and wrap them in `using` blocks so that disposals are handled correctly. Sounds like you need a singleton class that manages this one, persistent, connection so that the connection stays open and the temporary resources it has allocated remain active in SQL Server's view. How many clients will you be using? Beware that a single instance of SQL Server supports a maximum of 32,767 concurrent connections - if you're intending to have thousands of such clients you might want a different locking solution.

Comment: @DanGuzman: thanks for the nudge in the right direction: after double-checking, I found that the variable was indeed going out of scope